# Ubuntu : unattended apt-get upgrade : GRUB install dialog

Tags: 12.04, grub2, virtualbox, vagrant

People have run into this issue before :

[How to select GRUB install device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91642/how-to-select-grub-install-device)

[What do I select for "GRUB install devices" after an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23418/what-do-i-select-for-grub-install-devices-after-an-update)

but they weren't looking for an unattended solution.

Windows 7 + Virtual Box 4.2.16 + Vagrant 1.2.2

I'm creating an unattended Vagrant install/upgrade for precise64 (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server 64 ).

My `Vagrantfile` specifies to install precise64 image and then kick-off `boostrap.sh`

```
bootstrap.sh

apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
```

Things proceed along swimmingly until `apt-get upgrade -y` eventually pops-up this GRUP dialog :

```
The GRUB boot loader was previously installed to a disk that is no longer present, ...
```

Based on the forum posts referenced above, I know this to be a bogus warning and even if `/dev/sda` is selected for GRUB install device , the only way out of the dialog is to specify that GRUB not be installed.

However, I need a way to blow through this dialog for an unattended Ubuntu install/update/upgrade.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll want to change the debconf question priority and/or change the frontend to `noninteractive`. See [debconf(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/debconf.7.html)

Comment: Thanks geirha.  debconf is very interesting because my understanding is that a Vagrant virtual image of Ubuntu does not require a multi-boot-loader ( GRUB or otherwise ) , but I'm unclear as how to incorporate debconf into a shell that is meant to run in unattended mode.