# dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc no option to select boot device

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, dpkg

I need to reconfigure grub to use a different install device. Other threads indicate that there will be a screen that prompts me to select a device:

- [How to select GRUB install device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91642/how-to-select-grub-install-device)
- [How should one set the grub-pc package's "install_devices" debconf setting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135741/how-should-one-set-the-grub-pc-packages-install-devices-debconf-setting)

However, no such screen exists. It exits after the 2nd one.

How do I select the boot device?

**Screen 1**
[image]

**Screen 2**

[image]

**After Screen 2**

[image]

Comment: You appear to want `grub-install` , but your start of description asking for reconfigure (which won't do what you appear to want) has me a little confused of what you want; `grub-install` installs to different devices/drives

Comment: With UEFI you have to have an ESP. And Ubuntu's versions only install to first ESP it finds.  Grub install also default to first drive, but you can specify another ESP, but must only have one ESP per drive. See also: `man grub-install`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/617045/how-do-i-install-two-independent-ubuntu-installations-on-a-single-hard-drive-wit

Comment: @guiverc: no, OP is right - `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` should be the right thing to do here. `grub-install` will install GRUB once manually, and never update it again. `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` on the other hand will store the devices you've chosen in debconf, and then run `grub-install` on these devices on every GRUB/kernel update. Why it sometimes just won't ask I haven't been able to figure out myself yet, debconf sometimes is just super finicky :(

Comment: @OP: try `upgrade-from-grub-legacy` and then running `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`; the former resets the configuration stored in debconf, and should force `dpkg-reconfigure` to ask again. No idea though why it won't just work.

Comment: Ah, I think I've figured it out. Apparently I did debconf wrong, because it's actually grub-pc's postinst which decides whether to ask or not. It will *always* ask when `/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img` exists, and *never* if it does not. `/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img` should normally exist, and if it doesn't, something went wrong in the past. `upgrade-from-grub-legacy` is in fact the correct solution, because it will create the required `core.img`.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be [due to a change](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1889556) introduced to avoid potential corrupted systems.  I've filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1892526) about this as this just bit me during a RAID failure.

Update: The bug has been confirmed and triaged as high priority against basically all supported versions of Ubuntu.

Update #2: Fix has been released for Focal and Groovy!  I'm hoping someone on the Ubuntu team is tracking Bionic.

Update #3: Fix has been released for Bionic!

Answer (score 0):

`grub-pc`'s `postinst` decides whether to ask this question. In my case, I've tracked it down to the following condition:

```
        elif test -z "$2" || test -e /boot/grub/core.img || \
             test -e /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img || \
             test "$UPGRADE_FROM_GRUB_LEGACY" || test "$wubi_device"; then
```

So if `/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img` exists, it will *always* show the prompt. If it doesn't, it'll (practically) *never* show it.

`/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img` should exist under normal circumstances, so chances are, something went wrong in the past to cause this issue. To resolve the situation, run the following command:

```
upgrade-from-grub-legacy
```

This should create the required `core.img` and reset the installed devices debconf configuration, and afterwards `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` should work as expected.

You might be getting the following error, which is caused by a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943387):

```
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME is required
```

In this case, the following command should work:

```
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME=postinst DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE=grub-pc upgrade-from-grub-legacy
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Ubuntu 18.04. Even though ````core.img```` exists, ````upgrade-from-grub-legacy```` always says it doesn't and tries to create it. And dpkg-reconfigure still won't show the third screen.